# Flask return redirect(url_for('xyz')) causing TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, flask, redirect, typeerror

Please bear with me, I'm a complete noob and this is my 1st ever request for help so don't really know how to articulate the problem or what to provide to help articulate it.

I'm receiving the  "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" when a function is redirecting to a page a second time. The 1st time it redirects, things work ok.

I have an index page which displays some product information.  The index page extends a base.html page.  The base.html page holds a nav bar and the details of my cart.

When I add an item to my cart for the 1st time, the index page refreshes and displays the select items in the cart, when I click to add another item to the cart, the page crashes with the error.  This error occurs on the redirect line of code return redirect(url_for('product_info.index'))

```
``  #stores standard routes for the pages that can be seen post authenctication
    from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, session, url_for
    from sqlalchemy import or_, desc, asc, and_

    #work with flask_login to help with managing logged in users
    from flask_login import  login_required, current_user

    #bring in the tag types we sell 
    from .models import tag_types, plan_types
    from . import db

    #set up loggin
    import logging
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    import datetime


    #define this file is a blueprint of the
    #  application
    product_info = Blueprint('product_info', __name__)

    #define the routes now

    #define the main page of the website
    @product_info.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    #decorator, ensures you can only get to the home page if you are logged in

    def index():
    log.debug("Getting the tag types we sell")
   # log.info("user %s has entered the index page",current_user.user)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    log.debug("now set to %s", now)
    period = 'Monthly'
    log.debug("Set period to %s", period)
    log.debug("query if tag_types-valid_to_date is greater than or equal to %s or null to get valid sellable products", now)
    
    tags = tag_types.query.filter(or_(tag_types.tag_type_valid_to == None,             tag_types.tag_type_valid_to <= now)).all()
    log.debug(f"Query returned: {tags}")
    log.info("Tag types query executed successfully")

    log.debug("Getting the plan types we sell")
    log.debug("Get the pay monthly plans by querying if plan_types.plan_period = %s AND plan_types.plan_valid_to is null OR greater than or equal to %s OR plan_types.plan_valid_from less than or equal to the same date", period, now)
    log.debug("plan_types.plan_valid_to = %s and plan_types.plan_valid_from = %s", plan_types.plan_valid_to, plan_types.plan_valid_from)
    Subscription_plans = plan_types.query.filter(and_(plan_types.plan_period==period, or_ (plan_types.plan_valid_to == None, plan_types.plan_valid_to <= now,plan_types.plan_valid_from >= now))).order_by(plan_types.plan_period.asc(), plan_types.plan_min_tags.asc()).all()
    log.debug(f"subscriptin plans returned are: {Subscription_plans}")
    log.info("Get Subscription plans for sale retreived sucessfully")
    period = 'Pay as you Go'
    log.debug("Set period to %s", period)
    
    log.debug("Get the pay monthly plans by querying if plan_types.plan_period = %s AND plan_types.plan_valid_to is null OR greater than or equal to %s OR plan_types.plan_valid_from less than or equal to the same date", period, now)
    log.debug("plan_types.plan_valid_to = %s and plan_types.plan_valid_from = %s", plan_types.plan_valid_to, plan_types.plan_valid_from)
    Payasyougo_plans = plan_types.query.filter(and_(plan_types.plan_period==period, or_ (plan_types.plan_valid_to == None, plan_types.plan_valid_to <= now,plan_types.plan_valid_from >= now))).order_by(plan_types.plan_period.asc(), plan_types.plan_min_tags.asc()).all()
    log.debug(f"pay as you go plans returned are: {Payasyougo_plans}")
    log.info("Pay as you go plans for sale retreived successfully")

    return render_template("index.html", user=current_user, sub_plans=Subscription_plans, PYG_plans = Payasyougo_plans)

    #code to manage the shopping cart

    @product_info.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
    def add_product_to_cart():
    
        #try:
        _quantity = int(request.form['quantity'])
        _code = request.form['code']
        # validate the received values
        if _quantity and _code and request.method == 'POST':

            ordered_tag = tag_types.query.filter_by(tag_type_id = _code).first()
            log.debug(f"attempt to add item to cart, code passed in form is {_code}, results returned are: {ordered_tag}")
            hard_coded_price = 3.50
            hard_cooded_image = "Archie.jpg"
            itemArray = { ordered_tag.tag_type_id : {'name' : ordered_tag.tag_name, 'code' : ordered_tag.tag_type_id, 'quantity': _quantity, 'price' : hard_coded_price, 'image' : hard_cooded_image, 'total_price': _quantity * hard_coded_price} }
            
            log.debug(f"itemArray = {itemArray}")

            all_total_price = 0
            all_total_quantity = 0

            session.modified = True
            if "cart_item" in session:
                if ordered_tag.tag_type_id in session['cart_item']:
                    for key, value in session['cart_item'].items():
                        if ordered_tag.tag_type_id == key:
                            old_quantity = session['cart_item'][key]['quantity']
                            total_quantity = old_quantity + _quantity
                            session['cart_item'][key]['quantity'] = total_quantity
                            session['cart_item'][key]['total_price'] = total_quantity * hard_coded_price
                else:
                    session['cart_item'] = array_merge(session['cart_item'], itemArray)

                for key, value in session['cart_item'].items():
                    individual_quantity = int(session['cart_item'][key]['quantity'])
                    individual_price = float(session['cart_item'][key]['total_price'])
                    all_total_quantity = all_total_quantity + individual_quantity
                    all_total_price = all_total_price + individual_price

            else:
                session['cart_item'] = itemArray
                #this can be removed wehn we resolve the redirect issue
                itemArray = { 9 : {'name' : ordered_tag.tag_name, 'code' : ordered_tag.tag_type_id, 'quantity': _quantity, 'price' : hard_coded_price, 'image' : hard_cooded_image, 'total_price': _quantity * hard_coded_price} }
                session['cart_item'] = array_merge(session['cart_item'], itemArray)
                #end of temp code for debugging

                all_total_quantity = all_total_quantity + _quantity
                all_total_price = all_total_price + _quantity * hard_coded_price
    
            session['all_total_quantity'] = all_total_quantity
            session['all_total_price'] = all_total_price
            #log.debug("Session['cart_item'] has the following: %s", session['cart_item'])
            #log.debug("url_for %s", url_for('product_info.index'))
            #return render_template("index.html", user=current_user)
       
            return redirect(url_for('product_info.index'))
        
        else:
            return 'Error while adding item to cart'


    @product_info.route('/empty')
    def empty_cart():
     try:
      session.clear()
      return redirect(url_for('product_info.index'))
     except Exception as e:
      print(e)
 
    @product_info.route('/delete/<string:code>')
    def delete_product(code):
     try:
      all_total_price = 0
      all_total_quantity = 0
      session.modified = True
   
      for item in session['cart_item'].items():
       if item[0] == code:    
        session['cart_item'].pop(item[0], None)
        if 'cart_item' in session:
         for key, value in session['cart_item'].items():
          individual_quantity = int(session['cart_item'][key]['quantity'])
          individual_price = float(session['cart_item'][key]['total_price'])
          all_total_quantity = all_total_quantity + individual_quantity
          all_total_price = all_total_price + individual_price
        break
   
      if all_total_quantity == 0:
       session.clear()
      else:
       session['all_total_quantity'] = all_total_quantity
       session['all_total_price'] = all_total_price
   
      return redirect(url_for('product_info.index'))
     except Exception as e:
      print(e)

    def array_merge( first_array , second_array ):
        if isinstance( first_array , list ) and isinstance( second_array , list ):
            return first_array + second_array
        elif isinstance( first_array , dict ) and isinstance( second_array , dict ):
            return dict( list( first_array.items() ) + list( second_array.items() ) )
        elif isinstance( first_array , set ) and isinstance( second_array , set ):
            return first_array.union( second_array )
        return False`
```

I have tried so many different things.  the url_for returns a '/' which is expected.  and when putting that ('/') in the redirect, I get the same issue.

base.html looks like this

```
   `  <!-- content can go here in the base template-->      
      <div class = "container">
        
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          {% if 'cart_item' in session %}
        
          <p><a id="btnEmpty" href="{{ url_for('.empty_cart') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Empty Cart</a></p>
                   
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th class="text-center">Unit Price</th>
                <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                <th> </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for key, val in session['cart_item'].items() %}
              {% set quantity = session['cart_item'][key]['quantity'] %}
              {% set price = session['cart_item'][key]['price'] %}
              {% set item_price = session['cart_item'][key]['total_price'] %} 
            <tr>
              <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
              <div class="media">
                <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="/static/images/{{ session['cart_item'][key]['image'] }}" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading"> <a href="#">{{ session['cart_item'][key]['name'] }}</a></h4>
                  <h5 class="media-heading"> by <a href="#">Brand name</a></h5>
                  <span>Status: </span><span class="text-success"><strong>In Stock</strong></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              </td>
              <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" value="{{ quantity }}">
              </td>
              <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>£{{ price }} </strong></td>
              <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>£{{ item_price }} </strong></td>
              <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
              <a href="{{ url_for('.delete_product', code=session['cart_item'][key]['code']) }}" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
              </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
           {% endfor %}
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4"><h5>Total Quantity</h5></td>
              <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>{{ session['all_total_quantity'] }}</strong></h5></td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"><h3>Total</h3></td>
              <td colspan="2" class="text-right"><h3><strong>£ {{ session['all_total_price'] }}</strong></h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
              </button>
              </td>
              <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
               Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
              </button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
         {% else: %}
          <div class="no-records">Your Cart is Empty</div>
         {% endif %}
        </div>

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
      </div>`
```

relevant bits of INDEX.HTML looks like this

```
`    {% extends "base.html" %} 
    {% block title%}returnTag Home page{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}    
    <h1>Landing page</h1>
    <div id="rcorners2">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p> You're logged in {{ user.first_name}}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>sign up today!</p>
    {% endif %}
    <p>Here at returnTag, we're passionate about helping our customers recover the things important to them. Big or small, pet or person, if it's important to you, it's important to us. 
    That's why we have developed our products which, when scanned or tapped by the person who discovers your lost item or missing loved one, will display the information you want,  
    to help the finder return them safely to you.</p> 
    <p>Not only that, when someone does scan or tap your tag, you will receive a notification to your email and phone informing you of the scan of your returnTag.</p>
    <p>We offer variety of tag types for different uses, and these can be mixed and matched with the subscription and Pay as you Go offers we have on.</p>
    <br/>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="TagTypes" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" >Features</th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Pet Tag</th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Keyring Tag</th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Sticker Tag</th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Bracelet Tag</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">NFC technology</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">QR Code technology</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Custom online profile</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Real time alerts to your email</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Real time alerts to your phone</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">No batteries required</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Add family members</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; color:rgb(80, 206, 80)">&#10003;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="/add">
                    <div class="add-to-cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="code" value="6"/>
                        <input type="text" class="product-quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="default-btn" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="/add">
                    <div class="add-to-cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="code" value="8"/>
                        <input type="text" class="product-quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="default-btn" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="/add">
                    <div class="add-to-cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="code" value="9"/>
                        <input type="text" class="product-quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="default-btn" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="/add">
                    <div class="add-to-cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="code" value="7"/>
                        <input type="text" class="product-quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="default-btn" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>`
```

Comment: I should have pointed out the line of code causing the issue.....

In this function add_product_to_cart():  the return redirect(url_for('product_info.index')) is where it falls over.....  as stated, the 1st time you click the add to cart button (and go through the add_product_to_cart function, it redirects fine.  The 2nd time you click add to cart it falls over.........  tearing my hair out with it

Answer (score 0):

solved it.  The problem was in this line

```
itemArray = { 
    ordered_tag.tag_type_id : {
        'name' : ordered_tag.tag_name, 
        'code' : ordered_tag.tag_type_id, 
        'quantity': _quantity, 
        'price' : hard_coded_price, 
        'image' : hard_cooded_image, 
        'total_price': _quantity * hard_coded_price
    } 
}
```

The key, ordered_tag.tag_type_id was an integer.  When this is 1st set, that was ok.  When a new item was added to the array, for what ever reason flask changes the 1st key to string and adds the 2nd key as an integer.....

I changed the key to something else, that was a string and all worked ok.